# How to call an executable C in script shell?

Tags: c, linux, shell

How to call an executable C in script shell ?
I did echo `name_of_executable_file` but it didnt works

Comment: Sorry, did you compile your C code? How? Or do you want to run an executable from C? Maybe you need [system(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html) or [popen(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html). Read also about [path_resolution(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/path_resolution.7.html), [syscalls(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html), [environ(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/environ.7.html), [credentials(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/credentials.7.html)

Comment: Never describe a problem only as “it didnt works.” State exactly what you did, what behavior you observed, and what behavior you desire instead. For example, if the shell printed a message like “name_of_executable_file: command not found”, then say that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You call it like this:

```
/path/to/name_of_executable_file
```

Or if it's in the current directory, like this:

```
./name_of_executable_file
```

Comment: Or stick it somewhere in the executable path.

Comment: Or add the directory of name_of_executable_file to the PATH.

Answer (score 1):

use the below,

```
#!/bin/sh
/path/to/executable arg1 arg2
```

arg is optional